# Weird Plotting Results

Tags: r, plot, bigdata

I am trying to use R for some analysis on turtles and the problem is that whenever I do tutorials and try plotting it is fine, but when I use my real data set it gets weird. Attached is a photo of my results from trying to produce a simple scatterplot with:

```
attach(turtles)
plot(ccl, weight, main="Weight by CCL Scatterplot",
xlab="CCL ", ylab="Turtle Weight ", pch=19)
```

Any idea what's happening?

Thanks!
[image: Example]

Comment: look at the class of each of your variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ccl` and/or `weight` are probably `character` or `factor` classes.

Check this using this `R` code:

```
class(ccl)
class(weight)
```

and then turn the characters into numbers, e.g.:

```
ccl2 <- as.numeric(ccl)
weight2 <- as.numeric(weight)
```